# Global.asax Application_Start run on bin-folder update?

Tags: asp.net, global-asax, bin, application-start

My question is quite simple..
What if I have an application.. and I start it, and then I assume that Application_Start will be hit..
But what if I during runtime add another assembly to the bin-folder.. would this cause the application to rebuild and hit Application_Start again? (the assembly wont have any reference to the other assemblies or vice versa)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well... sorry, thought it was harder to test then it was... anyway.. the answer is YES, it does fire AppLication_Start again

Comment: Change in bin folder means app restart.